# hashlib import error when attempting to use pandas on App Engine?

Tags: python, pandas, google-app-engine

I'm attempting to deploy an app to App Engine, and am using pandas in it.

I've already downgraded pandas to a version low enough to correctly match the numpy that app engine installs (ie, pandas .16). Somehow I'm still hitting an error that seems related to missing c libraries? Or something? Anyone know what's up?

```
import pandas as pd
File "/base/data/home/apps<snip>/staging:<snap>/lib/pandas/__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
 from . import hashtable, tslib, lib
ImportError: dynamic module does not define init function (inithashtable)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is -

For Python 2 apps:

- *this can't currently be done with appEngine standard* and *use app engine flex*. Python2 Standard AppEngine instances only support a very reduced number of python modules with C extensions, and explicitly Pandas is not on the list

For Python 3 apps
* this is trivially easy to do See [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/specifying-dependencies)

---

The longer answer is:

- it may be possible, if you can somehow manage to compile the dynamically linked libraries correctly, so they'll get picked up correctly in app engine
- this is not something that's supported in GAE, and likely to be fragile and break
- just don't do it
- see this issue, and upvote it: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35894622